# Jquery UI Li sortable not working in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented exactly the one described in this [link](http://wil-linssen.com/entry/extending-the-jquery-sortable-with-ajax-mysql/) and the demo can be seen using this [url](http://demo.wil-linssen.com/jquery-sortable-ajax/) . But i tested in Internet explorer and it dosen't work. it works fine in firefox. Any help is seriously appreciated.The demo also dosen't work in the Internet explorer 9.

jquery 1.2.6 and jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom .

Comment: Did you try updating your jQuery version?

Comment: i can't because there are other things in the page and probably if i update i will break other things...

Comment: In which case I would recommend trying to update anyway, and if anything breaks, try to fix that, (it's easier fixing in an updated version, then an outdated one with less documentation). Also, nothing is likely to horribly break.

Comment: After some testing and googling..looks like its an issue with DivX, jQuery and IE9. Check this link: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/internet-explorer-9-jquery-and-divx

Comment: If u have looked the jsp page then probably u would also have said i don't wanna change any version... :)

Comment: FYI: jQuery < 1.6.1 is not fully compatible with IE9. Also, the demo works for me in IE7.

Comment: what about IE8...have u tried on IE8?

Comment: @Saurabh: Did you even try to check the page by disabling DivX if its installed?